# Metaplex uploading error. "path" argument must be string

Tags: solana, metaplex

I'm trying to use metaplex to upload NFTs and im having some issues with the uploading.

i'm running this command

```
 ts-node c:/server3/NFT/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts upload \ -e devnet \ -k C:\server3\NFT\keypair.json \ -cp config.json \ -c example \ c:/server3/NFT/assets
```

and getting this error [image]

now i know WHY im getting the error, it says because its skipping unsuported file "/server3" which is where the files are located. how do i make it not skip that folder? i believe thats why path is returning undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows has a issue with multi line commands. These new lines are indicated with the \ after every parameter. If you remove the extra \ and leave everything on one line it should resolve your issue for you.

`ts-node c:/server3/NFT/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts upload -e devnet -k C:\server3\NFT\keypair.json -cp config.json -c example c:/server3/NFT/assets`